# odata.nextLink is not part of the response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm following [this tuorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-driven-paging) to set up implement paging using odata v3 in asp.net web api 2

The generated odata controller method

```
public class Level2TableController : ODataController
    {
        private ProvisioningDMEntities db = new ProvisioningDMEntities();

        // GET: odata/Level2Table
        [EnableQuery(PageSize=10)]
        public IQueryable<Level2tableAllBudgets> GetLevel2Table()
        {
            return db.Level2tableAllBudgets.AsQueryable();
        }
}
```

and when I call the link like api/Level2Table?$top=5&$inlinecount=allpages
I get a odata response which doesn't include the nextPage Link

[image]

I tried all the options like setting the accept header to odata=verbose but it still doesn't return.

How do I get the nextPage link included as part of the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include `$top=<nr>` in your request OData will not supply a nextPage link.

Modify your request as follows:

```
HTTP GET api/Level2Table?$inlinecount=allpages
```

The service will return 10 entries in your case because that is the `PageSize` you set.